# Cross-browser CSS Tool

Tags: css, cross-browser

I was thinking this morning, my mind was on CSS and creating different style sheets for IE7, IE8, FF, etc.. I started wondering if there was a tool that exists to make this easier. I was thinking something along the lines of this:

1. Build the "core" style sheet.
2. Any time a "broken" rule is entered
       into the "core" style sheet, a fix
       is added to the associated browser
       specific style sheet.
3. If a fix is added it would also be
       noted, so you know that a particular
       style has extras in the browser
       specific sheets.

This could work in two different ways, either automatic, IDE style, or as a tool which you input the core css and output all the different css you need.

Thoughts? Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this is that the term "broken" is subjective. No machine is able to tell what you consider to be "broken". Granted there are some well-known bugs, but even then you're only really scratching the surface.

Your best bet is to just code using web standards and using a tool like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to make coding your CSS easier.

For instance, if you are using [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and want to add an IE6 specific rule, all you do is something like this:

```
#mydiv {
/* mydiv specific styles */
    .ie6 & { 
        /* IE6 specific styles for #mydiv
    }
}
```

Comment: The broken problem could be solved by basing your "core" in the standard and "broken" is what deviates from the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the SASS link, sounds interesting.

Comment: @aepheus true, but how can any software do that for you automatically unless you tell it what is "broken"?

Answer (score 0):

[Compass](http://compass-style.org) is doing some of what you were looking for. 
I know it is has been 5 years since you asked but this might help someone in pain :)